# Value based on a supplied standard-deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

Sorry if this is a very basic question, my statistics knowledge is very low!

I've got a dataset which is basically a set of greyscale values in a greyscale texture (ie. 0-255). What I want to do is take the mean value, and find out what the values would be at a specified standard-deviation to the left and right of the mean. Is this possible? I presume I'd have to presume a normal distribution?

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: I'm missing something: you have your dataset so you compute its mean *m* and standard deviation *s*.  The value at *z* standard deviations from the mean therefore equals m + z*s for any *z* you like.  Where is the problem?

Comment: @whuber Perhaps, the problem is that we cannot assume that the distribution is normal? It seems to me that the values are bounded from below (at 0) and from above (at 255). The normal may not make sense unless the standard deviation is very small and the mean far from the the boundary points. @Dan Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Srikant That's a reasonable guess.  But nothing in the current statement requires assuming any kind of distribution at all.  Perhaps the question really is about how to *interpret* values of the form m + z*s?  Regardless, although the question makes sense, it requires some amplification in order to elicit an answer that would be genuinely helpful.

Comment: In most cases the values will be nearer the high range (ie. nearer 255). The SD can also vary quite a lot unfortunately. As I mentioned in my post, I'm completely new to stats, so the formula you gave whuber might be what I want. I'll need to play around with various datasets to see if it works or not.

Comment: @Dan It would also help if you could tell us why you are doing this. As an aside: doing something like m + z*s may very well end with a upper bound of greater than 255 (depending on your values for m, z and s). Some sense of what you want to achieve (i.e., your goals) would help.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that easy to explain why I want it without writing a huge article worth of text. The upper bound going greater than 255 isn't a problem. It's the lower bound I need.
I think the m+z*s pretty much answers my question. Thankyou for that. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer. Unfortunately I don't have the rep to upvote.

Comment: @whuber See Dan's comment. Perhaps, you should post your suggestion as an answer for him to accept it. FYI.

Comment: @Srikant I am happy Dan has found something useful in these comments (and that you have helped him in that).  However, I am reluctant to post an answer to a question I just don't understand!  Remember, too--I think I'm recalling this correctly--it is this site's policy not to go to extraordinary efforts to help someone formulate their question, so I'm even more reluctant to restate what I think the question might be asking and then answer the restated question.  Whom would that serve?  Others should feel free to jump in and do this if they want some easy points.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you want to re-scale the values so that they have a specified standard deviation. If so, then it is easy.

Let's assume that you have a mean of x and a standard deviation of y, and the desired standard deviation is z. Subtract x from every observation, then divide them by y so that you have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of one. Now multiply by z and add x to each value. You will end up with the original mean, x, and a standard deviation of z.

This will work whatever the distribution of the data as it is simply linearly re-scaling the x-axis of the distribution.